# Can I use css to change font to rounded font?

Tags: css, fonts, web

[image: rounded font]

This image show you the mean of rounded font

I want the web page only use web safe fonts

but these fonts are not beautiful.

since I want the page as consistent as possible to every user, I cannot use non safe fonts.

so I hope solution can be found in css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `@font-face` rule. It allows loading custom typefaces.
I believe there is no other way to alter rendering of fonts using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and quickest (and cheapest) way of getting better looking fonts is through Google fonts http://www.google.com/webfonts/ However because they're free they're not always that great.

Alternatively for more professional fonts you can use a service such as https://typekit.com/ but this will cost you money.